# ArrayIndexOutofbound Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have this Data which is TAB separated:

```
col_1, data_1, ""
```

I have this code snippet

```
clean(x.split("\t")(0)),clean(x.split("\t")(1)),x.split("\t")(2))
```

While accessing the 3rd element  **x.split("\t")(2)** it gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBound

How to avoid this error. Also if the 3rd column is empty, I want to keep it empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lift()` to get array value as option. Like this:

```
x.split("\t").lift(2).getOrElse("")
```